# How to use minify with kohana?

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3, minify

I have minify from here : http://code.google.com/p/minify/
I want to use it with Kohana v3. Tried and couldn't get it working, (I dont understand
much of URL rewriting and stuff like that )

I googled and didn't find a single viable solution!!
Anyone who has successfully done this ?
Anyone willing to take the challenge ? :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hehe .. nice to see there are KO3 developers :D

Here is the solution : http://forum.kohanaframework.org/discussion/7226

Comment: I'm getting the "Class controller_min does not exist" error on that ? :(

Comment: "it's already configured with a route called minify, that maps to '/min',"

You should check that it is in place, if not .. try to add it to your bootstrap file.

Comment: done, added it to bootstrap.. now, it works only if I add groups.. otherwise, if I do this : `<link href="/min?f=file1.css,file2.css,file3.css&b=/css/" rel="stylesheet">`, it wont work..

Comment: Ya, I made it work [somewhat] but not completely.. I still get the ` open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/www/vhosts/testserver.webyog.com/subdomains/shrinath/httpdocs:/tmp)` issue by using it without creating groups